# Why won't this JqueryUI autocomplete hit its URL?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm wiring the following method to my document.ready function.  However, the "myAutoCompleteURL.aspx" URL is never being accessed (I have a breakpoint on the page, and it's never being hit).

Anybody know why this isn't working?  I'm new to the UI version of AutoComplete; I had previously only used the jquery-based (deprecated) version.

```
function myAutoComplete(myTextBox, myLabel, myHidden) {
    var myType = $(myLabel).html();

    $(myTextBox).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "../myAutoCompleteURL.aspx",
                data: { q: request.term, type: myType },
                success: function (myData) {
                    response($.map(myData, function (myItem) {
                        return { label: myItem.name, value: myItem.name, id: myItem.id }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(myTextBox).val(ui.myItem.name);
            $(myHidden).val(ui.myItem.id);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you post a link to a working version?

Comment: Does that `$.ajax()` call work outside the context of the autocomplete? Try just putting it on a page and passing in fixed values to see if that works. I believe you may need to use a dataType of `application/json`, and use a quoted JSON string for your data instead, for example.

Comment: I can see my application loading this URL instead: "/FileNotFound.htm?aspxerrorpath=/script/jquery/indicator.gif".  What is indicator.gif?  A jquery file?  It seems I'm using the wrong version of jqueryui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firebug and look for what URL is being hit instead. If nothing shows up in the console, then the javascript code is not working at all.

Comment: I had a problem in my CSS code.  Thanks for suggesting Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the ../ in your url. I used to have the same issue sometime ago.

Secondly have an error function in your ajax call. If it hits the error function, then there is some problem in your data and you need to correct that.

As @GregL mentioned in his comment, that you are using JSON and not application/json :)